# iOS app data storage always growing with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I have released few Flutter apps on the App Store, and some of them are not caching anything, others yes.

Today, after few weeks of usage, my app size (seen from the iPhone's storage settings) is more than 2GB.

My app size is 32Mo when downloaded from the store.

When i loop through all the Flutter directories :

- `getTemporaryDirectory()`
- `getApplicationDirectory()`
- `getApplicationSupportDirectory()`
- `getDownloadsDirectory()`

The sum returns more or less an additional 37Mo of cached files that i have saved from my code (using `Hive`), including the ones from `cached_network_image`.

When i download my app bundle on Xcode, the total app size is 96Mo.

I have raised this issue to Apple and didn't know what to tell me.

- Is there an iOS caching system that is always increasing for GPU cache for example ?
- Is it linked to a Flutter engine cache somehow ?

Thanks for any explanation to help me understand where these 2Go might come from.

Note : I see this behaviour in all of my Flutter apps, even in one where i don't use `cached_network_image`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672701/flutter-app-documents-and-data-disk-usage-is-too-high-on-ios ?

Comment: It's possible it's duplicate yes ! i will try what is said in the question you shared